# 'this' is misbehaving (again) inside an ES6 method

Tags: javascript, this, es6-class

Just getting started with ES6 classes.  As far as I understood it, **this** was supposed to behave predictably inside a class and always point to the object.  However, that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
class BodyPixController {

    #target; //Declare a private property

    constructor(target){
        this.#target = target; // Set the property

        console.log(this); // logs: BodyPixController {#target: 'photo'}

        addEventListener('load', this.init); // Calls the method
    }

    init() {
        console.log(this); // logs: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location,…}
        const img = document.getElementById(this.#target); // Throws error: Cannot read private member #target from an object whose class did not declare it
        console.log(img);
        async function loadAndPredict() {
            const net = await bodyPix.load( /** optional arguments, see below **/ );

            const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(img);
            console.log(segmentation);
        }
        loadAndPredict();
    }
}
```

In the code above, **this** only points to the instantiated object inside the constructor.  As soon as the init() method is called, **this** points to Window.  Why?  And how do I access private properties from inside methods?

Comment: should be: `addEventListener('load', () => this.init())`. Simply `this.init` is unbound.

Comment: To improve the question, consider to add a link to documentation (either ES spec or MDN) that explains where "*I understood it*, this was supposed to behave predictably inside a class and always point to the object" coming from.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside event listeners refer to the object that the listener is attached to in case of the `load` event the `Window`.

Either pass event listener as arrow function as they have no scope or bind this to your function in constructor like:

```js
constructor() {
  // bind this inside init to current object
  this.init = this.init.bind(this);

  addEventListener('load', this.init);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Binding will work, but arrow functions are better practice, I think.  I'm going to start using them by default so I hit fewer problems with this.

Comment: dont forget to green-tick your answer then @wagster (I'll delete this so as not to clutter the comments)

Answer (score 1):

"as far as I understood it", it's all [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Classes arent special, just syntactic sugar, so when you pass that function to the event listener, it wont be calling "yourObj.func()", just "func()" (for simplicity), it has no reference to your object.

You're thinking of ES6 functions, which *are* special. Change `init() {` to `init = () => {` and it'll behave how you want; `this` will *always* refer to your instantiated class object (not even `.apply()` can override).

Comment: Finally I get the point of arrow functions. This is the simplest solution.

Comment: it's annoying class methods aren't syntactic sugar for arrow functions but plain functions, having the `=` looks a lot less clean and I'd rather use `x = function() {` in the rare occasion you do want an old function, but yeah you basically always want an arrow function. I think `class` was put into ECMA before `=>` was so that'd be why

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can work with this.  I created a class and added an event handler; then created an instance of the class and triggered one of the events.

So here we have an event target `e.target` and `this` as things to work with.

```js
class BodyPixController {
  constructor(target) {
    this.target = target;
    console.log(this);
   this.target.addEventListener('load', this);
  }
  boundLoad = () => this.loadEvent()
  boundInit = this.init.bind(this)
  init(e) {
    console.log(e);
    const img = document.getElementById(e.target);
    console.log(img);
    async function loadAndPredict() {
      const net = await bodyPix.load( /** optional arguments, see below **/ );
      const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(img);
      console.log(segmentation);
    }
    loadAndPredict();
  }
  loadEvent(e){
        //  Some action related to the event (e)
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log("loadEvent:",this);
        console.log("What:",e.target.innerText);
    }
  handleEvent(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
      case "load":
        this.loadEvent(e);
        break;
      case "init":
        this.init(e);
        break;
    }
  }
}
var target = document.querySelector(".fun-target");
var myInstance = new BodyPixController(target);
target.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('load'), {})
```

```html
<div class="fun-target">howdy</div>
```

Comment: This will work but it's a bit too complex - I just needed to use an arrow function.

Comment: @wagster Perhaps, which is why I have the `boundLoad = () => this.loadEvent()` in here along with the bind option - use of either of those is probably a `choice` based on your other code.